# Does "fidget" describe someone walking, standing and sitting down continuously?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

The Oxford Learners Dictionary defines *fidget* as:

> **fidget (with something)**: to keep moving your body, your hands or your
>   feet because you are nervous, bored, excited, etc.  "*Sit still and
>   stop fidgeting!*" [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fidget_1?q=Fidget)

Would the above explanation describe the following action?

**Action A**: "*walking around the room and sometimes walking up and down in the room and sometimes sitting down but then standing up because of nervousness.*

I understand that the verb *fidget* means you are continuously moving your body / hand / feet while you are either standing or sitting down in one place. Thus, I think *fidget* does not describe action A.

If I am correct, then what are the word or  term  can I use to express "Action A"?

Comment: I'd call that ***pacing nervously***

Comment: 'Fidgeting' is not restricted to a single place.

Comment: Normally fidgeting implies doing so while sitting or standing in one place, but this is not writ in stone. It could include pacing, etc, and especially the sort of activity you describe -- sitting, standing, pacing, fooling with the curtains, etc, in a random pattern.

Comment: Your example doesn't fit "fidget" very well. If the reason was boredom it might work better, but in both cases the movement is too much to count as fidgeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would describe that as being restless, or behaving restlessly.

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.